# git: re-creating branch from scratch will overwrite PR?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

OK so I had to fix a bug. I branched off `master` and created `fixbranch`. When I thought to have finished, I pushed to my *own fork*. From there, I created a PR to the upstream repo, which would fix the issue. So far so good.

Now I've been told that my "fix" went astray, in that I chose an approach with no approval. I've been hinted on how to do it better, and most importantly to **force all commits into one single commit**.

The last issue is what I need a good solution for. I was going to re-create a new branch from `master`, then `git push -f origin fixbranch`, which would overwrite my push on my fork and update the PR. The question is, will this result in one commit for the PR also? Or should I better create a new PR and delete the original one?

Comment: The request for you to force all commits into a single one seems unnecessary since they can squash your commits during the merge from the pull request interface in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rebase or reset a branch and force push, your PR on the upstream will automatically reflect the new state of your updated branch. Your PR will have one commit.